# PHP -If we create object of child class in php, does it call parent class constructor and then child class constructor like java?

Tags: java, php

PHP -If we create object of child class in php, does it call parent class constructor and then clild class constructor like java?

Comment: What are you specifically concerned about? Which type of java constructors, the method or the static ones? And please add your code so it's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to call the parent constructor in child class.

```
public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  //...other code
}
```